# How to split multiple lines of the same feature using a line?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, splitting

So obviously there is a split tool to split a single selected line. In my instance I would like to split 2+ lines of the same feature using a tool that is similar to the split tool. 
[image]

In this image I have two road lines that are identical features. I want to split these lines using another line (the red line). I have tried a variety of different tools and the closest one to making it work is the

Answer (score 6):

There is one way to achieve this but it requires you to have at least a *Standard* desktop license.

1. Go into edit mode.
2. Create a new cutting line crossing the two lines, so you are creating a new feature in the same dataset.
3. Select all 3 lines.
4. Go to Editor > More Editing Tools > Advanced Editing toolbar.
5. Click on the [Planarize lines](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/splitting-lines-at-intersections-with-planarize.htm) button.
6. Select and delete out the 3 line segments from your cutting line.

You can use this approach to cut multiple parallel lines or even non-parallel lines if your cutting line is not straight.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This does work. The only issue is that time is of the essence and I have the regular split tool on a hotkey so that takes less time then this option. Once again thank you but it would have to be just as fast as the split tool.

Comment: When I say "I'd like to split these lines with another line", I don't mean a actual feature polyline. Just a tool that uses a line to split them. FYI

Comment: I don't think a tool exists that splits multiple selected polylines with a single line, hence the approach I suggested. If you know python or Arcobjects it would be easy enough to develop such a tool.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Yeah I believe a co-worker may develop such a tool. Just an obvious missing tool that ESRI doesn't have....